# How to make header only stick on negative content offset - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `tableView` and I have a UIView as the tableView header. I want the header to move up the screen when I scroll down and act just like any normal cell. But when I have reached the top of the view, where if I scroll up it will just bounce back, I want the tableView header to stick to the top.

One example is like the Facebook app headers. They scroll when you scroll, but if you're at the top of the page and you scroll up, they wont scroll down, they stay stuck to the top.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: So you just want to turn off bounce from `tableView`?

Comment: Try using tableView's section header instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a normal tableView (not grouped style) and you only have one section, you can accomplish this by using the section header instead.  The default behaviour of this type of tableView is as you described.  You'll just have to provide a custom view for the section header that looks like your cell.

If this isn't a possibility, you'll need to take advantage of tableView being a subclass of scrollView, and implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method to check content offsets etc.